# Изменение значения ползунка не отпуская клавиши

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть ползунок

```
<input type="range" min='500' max='1000' class='InRange' value='700' step='50'>
```

Значение ползунка изменяются только после отпускания клавиши.

```
$('.InRange').change(function(){
        console.log( $('.InRange').val())
})
```

**Вопрос, как сделать так чтобы изменения вступали в силу при зажатой клавише?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var value = $('.InRange').prev().attr('value');
    $('.InRange').html(value);
    $('.InRange').on('input',function(){
        console.log( $('.InRange').val())
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min='500' max='1000' class='InRange' value='700' step='50'>
```